# getRealPath() in jsp custom tag file using EL or scriptlet code

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I'm trying to access the servlet path from a tag file like so;

```
<%@tag description="put the tag description here" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%=pageContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")%>
```

However it complains it cannot find the symbol;
string:///xxxxx:89: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable pageContext
location: class org.apache.jsp.tag.web.xxxx

any suggestions on how to access that value in the tag file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the expression appears within a tag file, `pageContext` is not a valid implicit object. As you've noted, `application` is valid, so is `jspContext` (an instance of `javax.servlet.jsp.JspContext`). On a related note, it is possible that `getRealPath` will return `null`...

Answer (score 0):

oh, it looks like application.getRealPath("images") is the one in the tag context

Comment: No, it's the one in *scriptlet* context. You aren't calling it using a tag (e.g. (`<c:something>`) or EL (e.g. `${}`), but using an old fashioned *scriptlet*.